# Cannot debug Sharepoint application using non system account user?

Tags: sharepoint, debugging, sharepoint-2007, moss, wspbuilder

I am using `WSPBuilder` to develop `Sharepoint2007` sites, whenever i try to debug using one of the users that are not `System Account`, the debugger enters to the breakpoint and waits a step (F10), when i press F10, i get the following exception in the debug `output` window after pressing `F10` on the line having the breakpoint:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException'
occurred in XXX.dll
An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException'occurred in XXX.dll 
but was not handled in user code The thread '<No Name>' (0xfc4) has exited with 
code 0 (0x0).
```

and i am redirected to a page of sharepoint saying:

```
Go back to site   
Error: Access Denied
Current User   
You are currently signed in as: SHAREPOINT\ZZZ
Sign in as a different user
```

When i try to RUN not to DEBUG with the same user, I don't have this problem.

Also when i try to debug using the `System Account` (`MOSS ADMIN`), I don't have this problem ?

How to overcome this problem ? 

BTW, i am trying to debug a custom ASPX/CS page installed as a feature on the site.

FYI, it's only for this project not for all projects i have, also it's for all pages in this project not only one page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are interested, I found the solution: 
I created a new project and copied my files to it (of course with recreating  features), now it works fine. 
That means that the project itself is the problem not the IDE, perhaps some of its file are corrupted !

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try and add the user SharePoint\zzz to the WSS_WPG and WSS_Admin groups to see if that gets you around the issue. I assume you are doing the debugging on a single, stand alone install so you could also try and make SharePoint\zzz and administrator.

Comment: Thanks John, but I tried to add this user to both these groups, and i still have the problem. I also tried to give this user "Full Control" over the site (not only as "Contributor") but the problem still exists. PS, the problem only in debug not in run.

Comment: Is xxx.dll a SharePoint dll or a custom DLL? You may want to see the security rights are properly set for the DLL

Comment: Yes, John it is a sharepoint dll, it's the project created with wspbuilder. It RUNs well with this user, only not DEBUGging. BTW, how to check the security rights over a specific dll in GAC ? if it's a security right, i think it will nor neither run nor debug, but the problem is in debug only ?

Comment: Is the DLL deployed to the GAC? It's possible that could be the issue since there are no PDB files there. Possibly try deploying to the local bin folder of app to see if that allows for debugging.

Comment: Thanks John for your trials to help, anyway based on my several trials, I posted the solution that I found, you will find it marked as answer.